# Why do some directories mentioned in global-ignores still show up when running svn stat?

Tags: svn, cygwin, ignore

I'm running svn under Cygwin. This is the *global-ignores* line in my svn config:

```
global-ignores = .classpath .project ~*.docx *~ .settings
```

And yet I get the following result from *svn stat*:

```
$ svn stat
?       .settings/org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.superType.name
?       .settings/org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.superType.container
?       .settings/org.eclipse.m2e.core.prefs
?       .settings/.jsdtscope
```

Why does the *.settings* directory show up?
If I add *.foobar* to *global-ignores*

```
global-ignores = .classpath .project ~*.docx *~ .settings .foobar
```

and create a new directory *.foobar* it is hidden from the status as expected:

```
$ mkdir .foobar
$ ls -d .*
.  ..  .classpath  .foobar  .metadata  .project  .settings
$ svn stat
?       .settings/org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.superType.name
?       .settings/org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.superType.container
?       .settings/org.eclipse.m2e.core.prefs
?       .settings/.jsdtscope
```

I've also tried the following global-ignores:

```
global-ignores = .classpath .project .settings
```

but the .settings still show up in the status.

Comment: Have you done an `svn up` since you put the changes in? The meta data may not have been updated with the ignores for the _existing_ directories.

Comment: I have done several `svn up`, but still the annoying .settings show up.

Comment: Are those files you are trying to ignore still in the repo? If so, they'll get "oddly flagged".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `.settings` is a versioned item. Run `svn info .settings` to make sure. If it is versioned SVN won't ignore it - ignoring works only with unversioned items.

Comment: It turns out it is. I got confused by the '?'-flag. Thanks!